# Will remote-true link disable/break normal javascript behavior?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Will remote-true link disable normal javascript code ?

Every product  on my page has a **remote true(ajax)** link

The link will trigger another controller's method

```
  def add_item
    product = Product.find_by_id(params["product_id"].to_i)
    @cart.add(product, product.price    )
  end
```

And I also want to show modal(popup window) when click the link,

But it doesn't work on my Rails.

I think the **remote=true** break the javascript workflow, right ?

How could I also enable the **js remodal** popup when click the link ?

What's the better practice, if I want to trigger normal javascript call, and invoke the `remote=true` flow at the same time ?

## application.html.haml

```
  :javascript
    window.remodalGlobals = {
        namespace: "modal",
        defaults: {
            hashTracking: false
        }
    };  
  %script{:src => asset_path("remodal/jquery.remodal.js", :type => "text/javascript")}    
  #buy_items.modal{"data-remodal-id" => "contact-modal-success"}
    %h1 hihi
```

## product.html.haml

```
    = link_to add_item_carts_path(product.id), remote: :true, :class=>"add_to_cart","data-remodal-target" => "contact-modal-success" do
```

## UPDATE: the alert window not shown, but console log does work

#### product.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".add_to_cart").click ->
    alert "hi"
    console.log "test"
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either use JavaScript attribute to hide your HTML tag at first and then animate the showing effect without using the `remote: true` or

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { something_to_do }
end
```

might be required for your remote call to js file